# First line of code in case is marked as unreachable but second line is not, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, switch-statement

According to Visual Studio 2015 the first line of code in the first `case` statement is unreachable but I don't understand why. The second line of code in the same `case` statement is not marked as unreachable and all the code in the `default` statement is reachable. Is VS just being stupid or am I missing something here?

```
private static void LogToITSupport(string ErrorType)
{
    var Email = new MailMessage();
    Email.To.Add("");
    Email.From = new MailAddress("");

    switch ("ErrorType")
    {
        case "Database Connection":
            Email.Subject = "JobSight Error, unable to connect to database.";
            Email.Body = "JobSight is unable to connect to the JobSight database, this could indicate the databse is dow nor there is a server problem. Please investigate.";
            break;

        default:
            Email.Subject = "JobSight has encountered an unknown error.";
            Email.Body = "JobSight has encountered an unknown error and thinks that IT should fix it. Good Luck.";
            break;
    }

    var Client = new SmtpClient("");
    Client.Send(Email);
}
```

Comment: that's compiler smartness, it is intelligent enough understand

Comment: "ErrorType" should not be encased in quotes. You're looking at a literal string there.

Comment: change ``switch ("ErrorType")`` to ``switch (ErrorType)``

Comment: Yep, fat fingered that and did not even notice it. Been a long rough day. Thanks, @CharlesMay if you want to throw it as an answer I will mark it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its clearly a typo by the poster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In answer to your actual question. You are switching on a literal string "ErrorType" and your options are "DataBase Connection" or Anything else.

Since the compiler is looking at a literal string, it knows that DataBase Connection will never be the case so it's unreachable.

If for example you changed your switch to "DataBase Connection" you would notice that the first line would be ok but then you would receive that error on the default because the compiler knows that Database Connection is the only thing that can be reached.

With the use of the actual variable switch(ErrorType) the compiler doesn't know what will be passed in and so both the case and the default is possibly reachable.

As pointed out by others, remove the quotes because you're wanting to switch on the string that your variable ErrorType holds.

Answer (score 4):

The string literal `"ErrorType"` can never be equal to `"Database Connection"` so the compiler is just telling you that.

You might want to use the `ErrorType` variable instead:

```
switch (ErrorType)
{
    case "Database Connection":
        Email.Subject = "JobSight Error, unable to connect to database.";
        Email.Body = "JobSight is unable to connect to the JobSight database, this could indicate the databse is dow nor there is a server problem. Please investigate.";
        break;

    default:
        Email.Subject = "JobSight has encountered an unknown error.";
        Email.Body = "JobSight has encountered an unknown error and thinks that IT should fix it. Good Luck.";
        break;
}
```

Now if the `ErrorType` variable equals to `"Database Connection"` then the first statement will be executed, otherwise the default one. And this evaluation will be done at runtime depending on the value of the string variable.